# Help with Spring3.0 MVC/Hibernate/HibernateDaoSupport integration

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

### Mapping

<bean id="signinDAO" class="com.socialshop.authentication.dao.SigninDAOImpl">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

### DAO

```
public interface SigninDAO{
        public List<DataObject> getList();
}

public class SigninDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport {
         public List<T> getList() {
  return (getHibernateTemplate().find("from " + dataClass.getName() + " x"));
 }
}
```

### Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/signin.html")
public class Signin {

 private SigninDAO signinDAO;
 Signin(){ 
 }

 public void setSigninDAO(SigninDAO signinDAO) {
  this.signinDAO = signinDAO;
 }

 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("signinRequest") SigninRequest signinRequest,
   BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

  List<Merchant> merchant = signinDAO.getList();

   return "index";

 }

}
```

When my signin form is posted processSubmit method is called and I get null pointer Exception  here `List<Merchant> merchant = signinDAO.getList();`

Looks like `setSigninDAO()` method is not mapped with this request? How do I map it?
How do I use multiactioncontroller in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You need to annotate your dependency setter method with `@Autowired`:

```
@Autowired 
public void setSigninDAO(SigninDAO signinDAO) {   
    this.signinDAO = signinDAO;  
}
```

**See also:**

- [3.9 Annotation-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)

Comment: Thanks @axtavt, that worked. I need to do more reading now ;)